# What is the story of the Tarakeshwar Temple in West Bengal?

Tags: shiva, shiva-lingam

A man told me that the Shiva Linga of Tarakeshwar had grown automatically; what is the real story? And why is the Linga’s name Taraknath?

Answer (score 2):

The Tarakeshwar temple was built in 1729 AD. In the temple, there is a tank named Dudhpukur which is believed to fulfill the prayers of those who taking a dip in it.

As per local legends, this temple was built after knowing about it in a dream. This dream led the mendicant brother of Raja Vishnu Das to a Linga in the jungles near Tarakeshwar which is located in Hooghly, West Bengal. This temple was later built around a Swayambhu Linga, referred as Baba Taraknath in 1729 AD.

Nowadays, in the Shravan month, people go to Tarakeshwar by walking from Kolkata which is the capital of West Bengal and did abhishek of Baba Taraknath in Tarakeshwar.